# Why doesn't this style property assignment work as expected in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've tested the below code on React Native in my browser (using Expo CLI Webpack) and the result is three green squares down the left side of the screen.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const styles = {
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  backgroundColor: "green"
};

const Rectangle = (label, value) => {
  return (
  <View style={[styles, {[label]: value}]}/> // Line I expect to modify style.backgroundColor
  );
};

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: "space-evenly"}}>
    <Rectangle label="backgroundColor" value="red" />
    <Rectangle label="backgroundColor" value="green" />
    <Rectangle label="backgroundColor" value="blue" />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

However, I expected to see a red, green and blue square.  I've tried to mimic a pattern used several times on this [page](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox) of the RN documentation but it isn't behaving as I expected.  Could someone please explain what I've misunderstood here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Props will be passed as a single object attribute, not as multiple attributes.

Simply replace `(label, value)` with `({label, value})`.

By putting curly braces around your props you're destructing the first attribute, which in this case is your props.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your code.

First, as Ugur Eren mentioned, you are not destructuring your props.

Second, you are putting your styles ***objects*** into an ***array***.

```
const Rectangle = ({label, value}) => { //<-- use destructuring. See Ugur Eren answer
  return (
  <View style={{...styles, [label]: value}}/> //<-- use an object. Use spread syntax to stack values
  );
};
```

Using [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) allows you to build a new object, stacking values that are passed in (or build a new array, appending values that are passed in).

It looks like this is already what you are trying to do, except you were using an array (which won't overwrite/stack values) and missing the spread syntax operator (`...`).

### Edit: array syntax correct

Looks like I'm wrong about this -- the Array syntax for style is correct. It is used in the [official React Native documentation on style](https://reactnative.dev/docs/style):

```
        <Text style={[styles.bigBlue, styles.red]}>bigBlue, then red</Text>
```

Weirdly, there is no mention of this in the React documentation on style, neither [on the DOM elements page](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style) nor in the [FAQ on styling](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html), which only mention using Objects to pass style.

Comment: @UgurEren just figured this out. Didn't know that.

Comment: @UgurEren Weirdly, only the React Native docs mention this. React docs only mention using objects, but I can't imagine that this is specific to RN

Comment: I've never used react on the web, so i can't comment on that but i agree, react should support it too if it doesn't.

Comment: Learn something new every day. Thanks for the info

Comment: My pleasure, also seems like react doesn't support it, it's RN specific: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-3ttu0?file=/index.js

Comment: Strange! Thanks for checking!!